# Дубликаты в массиве

Tags: php

Есть такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test1@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test2@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test2@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test3@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

)
```

Хочу получить такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test1@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test2@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VALUE] => test3@test.ru
                    [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                )

        )

)
```

Код

```
function array_unique_key($array, $key) { 
    $tmp = $key_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
 
    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $tmp[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $tmp; 
}

$email_work = array_unique_key($email_work, 'VALUE');
print_r($email_work);
```

Но почему-то выводит дубликат, а не массив без дублей.
Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте пример из документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php#116302

Comment: @Jour  я так и делал

Comment: переменная $i бессмысленна, достаточно $tmp[] = $val

Comment: отлично все работает https://onlinephp.io/c/0b129

Comment: но я бы еще сократил код https://onlinephp.io/c/bfbda